# Best practice for secureing an existing socket connection, without SSL

Tags: sockets, security, ssl, ssh

In [Best practice for secure socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599791/best-practice-for-secure-socket-connection), the OP wants to secure the connection between two sockets, without SSL.

[Thomas Pornin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600302/2829411) suggests SSH is the answer.

1. Is this answer based on SSH ***port forwarding*** of existing sockets, or just switching to SSH in general?
2. If not, and the question was how to make existing sockets more secure without SSL, what is the best way to to do that?
3. If a client on port 10 connects to a server on port 20, how can the server restrict access so that only client on port 10 can connect? And that it really is the client on port 10 (not an imposter)? (**Availability** only for an **authenticated** client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer there is any form of the SSH protocol, which is based on channels. You can use those channels to transmit fairly arbitrary information, including port-forwarded data or terminal sessions, or anything you can turn into a byte stream. That said, TLS is generally much easier to implement in code because the libraries are ubiquitous and designed to be used this way. SSH is easier to implement in scripts on Unix-like systems because it has a powerful command-line API.

In most cases, TLS is the better choice. Unless you have a very specialized problem, TLS is almost always the better choice. So the question here is, what problem do you have that TLS doesn't work for? If it's "I hate TLS" then sure, SSH. But TLS is better in most cases.

TLS authenticates using client certificates. SSH authenticates using your private key. In either case, the cert/key is stored in a file that the client reads and uses to authenticate to the server.

It's not clear from your question what you mean by "client" or "imposter" here. Anything that has access to the cert/key will be authorized (possibly requiring a user-provided password), so those must be protected. If when you say "client" you mean "my application," that is not a solvable problem. You can authenticate people. You can to some extent authenticate machines (particularly if you have an HSM or similar piece of security hardware available). You can weakly authenticate that client is *claiming* to be on port 10, but this is generally useless and extremely fragile, so I wouldn't pursue it. You cannot authenticate software over the network in any meaningful way.

Short answer, though, is to use TLS unless you have a very specialized problem and a good security expert to help you design another solution (and your security expert will almost certainly say "use TLS").

Comment: ok, thanks that makes sense. by "client" vs. "imposter" - in this case, I just want to funnel all the data between the client/server via SSH...so the sockets don't even "know" anything about the SSH in between them....however, I do want to ensure that while this tunnel is active, nobody else can access the server application at that port (where before anyone could).

Comment: That probably is a good use of SSH port-forwarding. It's very good at being transparent to the software.

Comment: however, it's still just a question - how would I ensure nobody else can access the server application at that port, once the tunnel is active ? (where as before that port was open to anyone).... will SSH now block that port from all other access?

Comment: There may be a confusion here about how unix ports work. What are you trying to protect?

Comment: trying to deny all other connections, unless that connection is via the SSH tunnel.

Comment: That will either have to be done in the server process itself or in a proxy process. The proxy would just not listen to anymore connections once it's accepted one. Accepting multiple connections is something processes have to do on purpose. The proxy would accept one connection and just forward it to the server process. (Or the server can be rewritten to only accept one connection.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120277/discussion-between-p-s-and-rob-napier).